# Programmatically modifying parental controls on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, automator

Mac OS has a very basic set of parental control options that allow you to limit user's access to websites and apps, as well a set daily time limits. I want to be able to script this to do something like the following:

Allow access from 8am to 9:30 am for specific sites, restrict access to games.
Allow general access from 5pm to 6:00 pm.

I'm not sure where to start in terms of scripting this on Mac OS 10.8. Any suggestions? Is this something Automator can handle or am I better off using a cron job/shell script?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea for an app. Not sure if Apple would allow it on the mac app store, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Parental Controls are enforced using the regular ol' Managed Preference (aka MCX) frameworks that have been around since 10.2. It stores them in the local directory services in the mcx_attributes attribute for the user in question.

To set them, or any managed setting, outside of the GUI all you need to do is feed in a properly formatted plist using the mcx plugin of the `dscl` tool into the user. Using local directory service policy like this is well understood and documented by the OS X sysadmin community.

The easiest way to get started with understanding this is to setup some Parental Controls, then inspect the mcx attributes using the Directory Utility app from /System/Library/CoreServices or the `dscl` command which will let you explore your directory services as if it were a file system with cd and ls.

Once you see what the keys are that get set in the XML you can start crafting your own. You can also use the `dscl . -mcxexport` command. This will dump the management configuration out and you can then import it later. Check out `dscl . -mcxhelp` for the lowdown on the mcx plugin.

To review the process of implementing this with a script is:

1. Create a xml plist that contains the policy information you want.
2. Import that plist onto the proper account with `dscl . mcximport`

A more forward looking alternative would be to create a Configuration Profile (Which is just a plist file as well.) and then load it with the `profiles` command. If you take the configuration profile route then there isn't any messing about in directory services or the `dscl` command to worry about.

Comment: My server doesn't appear to have the MCX plugin. Any idea if there's a way to command-line manage parental controls without it?

Comment: What version of the OS are you running? It's there still in 10.9 with the addition of a mcxprofiles plugin as well. It's NOT in the man page. Just start dscl and then type 'help' to see all the usage.

Comment: Thanks @macshome, I found it.  I am running 10.8.5.  Don't know how I missed it at first.

Comment: http://blog.takelap.com/2010/05/how-to-set-mac-os-x-parental-controls.html has an example of scripting it, FWIW...

Answer (score 3):

To set the Guest account login times (time limits, or curfew):
Use the following long comnand, edit the values for start and end for each day.

```
dscl . -mcxedit /Users/Guest com.apple.familycontrols.timelimits limits-list '({allowancesActive = 1;curfews = {friday = ({end = "06:00:00";start = "00:00:00";},{end = "23:59:59";start = "17:00:00";});monday = ({end = "06:00:00";start = "00:00:00";},{end = "23:59:59";start = "17:00:00";});saturday = ({end = "06:00:00";start = "00:00:00";},{end = "23:59:59";start = "17:00:00";});sunday = ({end = "06:00:00";start = "00:00:00";},{end = "23:59:59";start = "17:00:00";});thursday = ({end = "06:00:00";start = "00:00:00";},{end = "23:59:59";start = "17:00:00";});tuesday = ({end = "06:00:00";start = "00:00:00";},{end = "23:59:59";start = "17:00:00";});wednesday = ({end = "06:00:00";start = "00:00:00";},{end = "23:59:59";start = "17:00:00";});};groupID = "__COMPUTER__";itemType = "com.apple.familycontrols.timelimits.computer";name = Computer;})'
```

To see the status of guest account time limits:

```
dscl . -mcxread /Users/Guest com.apple.familycontrols.timelimits limits-list
```

or:

```
dscl . -mcxread /Users/Guest com.apple.familycontrols.timelimits limits-list | egrep "end|start" | sort | uniq
```

FILES INVOLVED:
*/Library/Managed Preferences/Guest/com.apple.familycontrols.timelimits.plist*
Contains curfew data for local Guest account

*/Library/Managed Preferences/Guest/complete.plist*
Compilation of all Managed Preference settings for Guest account

This is the data that the system uses to set the curfew:
*/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/Guest.plist*