# SwiftUI: How to apply content blocker to chrome?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios-extensions, safari-content-blocker

I'm currently working with the content blocker Extension which works just fine for Safari.
But does anyone know if it can also be applied to Chrome, if so how?

Another question I have: Is it possible to block an app, with the content blocker Extension or some other way

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/creating_a_content_blocker):

> Content Blockers are app extensions that you build using Xcode. They indicate to **Safari** a set of rules to use to block content in the browser window. Blocking behaviors include hiding elements, blocking loads, and stripping cookies from **Safari requests**.

So it is not possible to block Chrome requests via Content Blockers.

For the other question you have, you can enable or disable any content blocker extensions from Safari's settings. Check [here](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/enable-content-blockers-safari/#:%7E:text=Launch%20the%20Settings%20app.,to%20the%20green%20ON%20position.) for more information.

If you are asking for a solution which blocks the apps, there are no way to programmatically do this in iOS (there may be some ways for jailbroken devices), at least to my knowledge.

1. You can check out Apple MDM [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/mdm-overview-mdmbf9e668/web).
2. For Mac OSX, you can check modifying parental controls, examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199540/how-to-check-parental-controls-with-objective-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320187/programmatically-modifying-parental-controls-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: Thanks, maybe I wasn't very clear about the second question, what I meant to ask was Is it possible to block another app for example Facebook or Snapchat with content blocker or some other way @Burak Akkas

Comment: I think you can block their websites and maybe deeplinks but it shouldn't be possible to block an app with content blocker since it specific for Safari requests only.

Comment: Okay I see, but what about blocking an app using something else than content blocker @BurakAkkas

Comment: Programmatically, that's also not possible. But you can check Apple's MDM guides for creating a profile for devices.

Comment: Is it not possible for both iphone AND Mac? @BurakAkkas